# GWT equivalent of an intent

Tags: android, gwt

I am just starting off with Google Web Toolkit, coming from programming in Android. Since it's all java(ish) I expected it to be similar. In my app I have an entrypoint where the user will upload an excel file and hit submit. After they hit submit they should be taken to a new page where I will be displaying some information from the excel that they just uploaded.

In Android it would look something like

```
        myAndroidBTN.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            try { 
               final Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, NextClass.class)); 
               startActivity(myIntent); 
       } catch (Exception e) { }       
        }
```

In the GWT App I have

```
Button btnSubmit = new Button("Submit");
    btnSubmit.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) { 
        }
    });
```

Documentation for GWT is doesn't seem to be anywhere near what it is for android so I can't find the right way to open a new java file. How should this be done?

**EDIT**
Some of you have miss-interpreted my question. I don't want to imply that I can build the equivalent of an android app in a browser with GWT, I just wanted to see the equivalent of an OnClick event taking you to a new page/section.

Comment: It's not really remotely similar--Java is just the implementation language. The frameworks are dissimilar.

Comment: I was starting to think this, but surely GWT apps have more than one UI page that are linked together?

Comment: Your question is not clear. GWT is a client-server framework. You can't manipulate a file on the client side, so you will have to send the file to the server using a FormSubmit, process the file on the server and then send back the information you wish to display. As said above, this is not at all like Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at Activities and Places.

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces